# How to get a concatenated string using IsNullOrEmpty when the field maybe empty

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I need to get the first initial of middle name but some entries are empty. If the Middle_Name field is empty, the substring causes the entire name string to be null.  I thought this code would work around a possible null field but now I get concat error.

```
li = (From e In Employees _ 
      Group Join j In Jobs On e.Jobcode Equals j.JobCode Into ej = Group_ 
      From j In ej.DefaultIfEmpty _ 
      Where SqlMethods.Like(e.Last_Name, lastName & "%") Or j.JobCode.Contains(jobCode) _ 
      Order By e.Last_Name, e.First_Name_Used _ 
      Select ID = e.EmployeeID, RACFID = e.Racf_id, _ 
             Name = e.Last_Name & ", " & e.First_Name & " " & If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Middle_Name), "", e.Middle_Name.Substring(0, 1))).ToList
```

The `Name = e.Last_Name ........` is giving me a Concatenation error.:

> Could not translate expression 'Concat(new [] {$VB$It.e.Last_Name, ", ", $VB$It.e.First_Name, " ", IIF(IsNullOrEmpty($VB$It.e.Middle_Name), "", $VB$It.e.Middle_Name.Substring(0, 1))})' into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.

Any Ideas? A null middle_Name causes the entire name string to be null

Comment: Put the code *here*.  Not a link to a picture of code.  Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: li = (From e In Employees _
  Group Join j In Jobs On e.Jobcode Equals j.JobCode Into    ej = Group_
  From j In ej.DefaultIfEmpty _
  Where SqlMethods.Like(e.Last_Name, lastName & "%") Or j.JobCode.Contains(jobCode) _
  Order By e.Last_Name, e.First_Name_Used _
  Select ID = e.EmployeeID, RACFID = e.Racf_id, _
             Name = e.Last_Name & ", " & e.First_Name & " " & If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Middle_Name), "", e.Middle_Name.Substring(0, 1))).ToList

Comment: [Edit] your post and put the code in the post. Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: Got your code in the question, but it doesn't match your image. Do as Plutonix said and edit your question to make it look nice (check the preview first...)

Comment: Just make sure that there is at least one character to invoke Substring(0, 1) on: `Name = e.Last_Name & ", " & e.First_Name & " " &  (e.Middle_Name & " ").Substring(0, 1).Trim()`. Or could `e.Middle_Name` be `NULL` in the database?

Comment: Yes, the database middle_name field is sometimes empty

Comment: @thomasjohnson Empty, as in "", is not the same as `NULL`.

Comment: Try calling `.ToString()` on e.Middle_Name, and e.Last_Name, e.First_Name in your LINQ query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    If li Is Nothing Then
        li = (From e In Employees _
        Group Join j In Jobs On e.Jobcode Equals j.JobCode Into ej = Group _
        From j In ej.DefaultIfEmpty _
        Where (SqlMethods.Like(e.Last_Name, lastName & "%") Or j.JobCode.Contains(jobCode)) _
        Order By e.Last_Name, e.First_Name_Used _
        Select ID = e.EmployeeID, RACFID = e.Racf_id, _
                   Name = e.Last_Name & ", " & e.First_Name & " " & If(e.Middle_Name IsNot Nothing, e.Middle_Name.Substring(0, 1), ""), _
                   Contract = e.Contract, _
                   Title = j.Title, Gang = j.Gang, _
                   SupvName = (From e1 In Employees _
                               Join j1 In Jobs On e1.Jobcode Equals j1.JobCode _
                               Where j1.JobCode = j.NextJobCode _
                               Select sup = e1.Last_Name & ", " & e1.First_Name & " " & If(e1.Middle_Name IsNot Nothing, e1.Middle_Name.Substring(0, 1), "")).First.ToString())

    End If
    Return li
```

This is the code I wound up using.  It works great.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Sql server as IO device. It purpose only read and write data.
Formatting is responsibility of your application.
In `.net` it will be much more easy, maintainable and cleaner(readable)

```
Dim employeesData = 
     From e In Employees
     Group Join j In Jobs On e.Jobcode Equals j.JobCode Into ej = Group
     From j In ej.DefaultIfEmpty
     Where SqlMethods.Like(e.Last_Name, lastName & "%") Or j.JobCode.Contains(jobCode)
     Order By e.Last_Name, e.First_Name_Used 
     Select e 

For Each e In employeesData
    Dim formattedData = New With
    {
        .ID = e.EmployeeID, 
        .RACFID = e.Racf_id,  
        .Name = $"{e.Last_Name}, {e.First_Name} {If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Middle_Name), "", e.Middle_Name.Substring(0, 1))}"          
    }

    Yield formattedData
Next
```

Comment: I am getting errors that say "VB9.0 does not support iterators".  Also "End of statement expected".

Comment: I am getting errors that say "VB9.0 does not support iterators".  Also "End of statement expected". Also does not support impliciant line continuation